# How to drop entire record if more than 90% of features have missing value in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, drop

I have a pandas dataframe called `df` with 500 columns and 2 million records.

I am able to drop columns that contain more than 90% of missing values.

But how can I drop in pandas the entire record if 90% or more of the columns have missing values across the whole record?

I have seen a similar post for "R" but I am coding in python at the moment.

Comment: do you want to drop rows where 90% are NaN? or do you want to drop columns if 90% are missing?

Comment: I want to drop rows where 90%+ of the columns have a NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.dropna()` and set the `thresh` parameter to the value that corresponds to 10% of your columns (the minimum number of non-NA values).

```
df.dropna(axis=0, thresh=50, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I think this is the correct approach. +1. But `thresh` should be `thresh=len(df)*0.1`, right?

Comment: Depending on if your number of columns is variable or not. If it is always 500 columns, then I would just use ‘50’ for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

You could use `isna` + `mean` on `axis=1` to find the percentage of NaN values for each row. Then select the rows where it's less than 0.9 (i.e. 90%) using `loc`:

```
out = df.loc[df.isna().mean(axis=1)<0.9]
```